# SharePoint error

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint site and today when I try to login to the site it gives me the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *Runtime Error Description:*
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> *Details:*
> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you reach other pages and sites at this SharePoint installation? In example www.yoursharepoint.com/_layouts/settings.aspx

Comment: Did you try following the suggestions that are in the error message that you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the custom error mode to remote only in your web.config file and try browsing the site again. This time you will get the detailed error with the stack trace. You can proceed from there.

Comment: this is generic error and unless you get the detailed error report its hard to predict.It might be due to exceptions while compiling a resources required in your application, missing tags in your web.config,etc.

Answer (score 5):

I've got to change this file:

You may also need edit the web.config in the layouts folder of the SharePoint root:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config

And set

> <customErrors mode="Off" />

Comment: Thanks, I finally found where the file is located.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following in web.config and you will be able to see the detailed error.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

and

```
CallStack="true"
```

Make sure you do this in all the WFEs. You will see detailed error. Once you have the detail error, post it here and we will be able to helop you more.

Comment: sorry ignore my above comment :-) I did not see the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server then try... Because in my case during I install visual studio on my server system, i can't access my site and i got same error what you posted in above, after restarted my server its works fine. that's why i am saying like that...

What i thought is, actually that time the IIS was disturbed by some other installation program.